# Use maven module in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project (gradl) in my android studio and I have a maven module, I would like to use in my android project. The structure is as follows:

- Androidproject (gradle)

  - Subproject (gradle)
  - -- build.gradle
  - MyFancyStuff (gradle)
  - -- ...
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradl
- shared-models (Maven project)

  - pom.xml
  - ...

Now I adjusted my `settings.gradle` as follows:

```
include ':MyFancyStuff',':shared-models'
project(':shared-models').projectDir = new File('../shared-models')
```

I got this from several other stackoverflow topics.

Now the `build.gradle` of the subproject:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'MyFancyStuff:MyFancyStuff-debug@aar'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile project(':shared-models')
}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    ivy {
        url "../shared-models"
    }
}
```

Now I get the following error:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Based on other threads on stackoverflow, I don't know the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question and in case anybody needs this as well. 
The maven project can be installed locally with `mvn install`.

The project can be loaded afterwards, but wen need to include the local repositories with

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Then, dependencies can be loaded within the dependencies section like

```
dependencies {
   ....
    compile 'groupId:artifactId:version'
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

**It means that Gradle is looking for a module (or a `build.gradle`) file, and it's not finding it.**

In your case the issue should be the shared-models which is a Maven project with
`pom.xml` instead of `build.gradle` file.

Gradle doesn't provide native support for parsing POM files, but Groovy's [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper) makes XML parsing easy and convenient.
Check also this [link](http://willis7.github.io/blog/2015/02/read-pom-from-xml.html)

Comment: So using a maven module in gradle is not possible?

Comment: For my experience Gradle doesn't provide native support for parsing POM files, but Groovy's [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper) makes XML parsing easy and convenient. Check also this link:http://willis7.github.io/blog/2015/02/read-pom-from-xml.html